# Как получить src файла и добавить в почтовый шаблон?

Tags: php, битрикс, sendmail

При регистрации на сайте пользователь загружает файлы (6 шт.) , далее данные этого пользователя попадают в админку, информация о файлах попадает в кастомные поля, для примера карточка клиента - **UF_DOCUMENT_6**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно отправить все вложения нового пользователя через почтовый шаблон админу . в init.php письмо юзеру и админу уходит таким образом :

```
  function OnBeforeUserRegisterHandler(&$arFields)
{
   AddMessage2Log("OnBeforeUserRegisterHandler");

   $filter = Array("ID" => $arFields["ID"]);
    $rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="personal_country"), ($order="desc"), $filter); // выбираем пользователей
    while($arUser = $rsUsers->GetNext()) {
        $user_active = $arUser["ACTIVE"];
    };
    if ($arFields["ACTIVE"] == 'Y' && $user_active == "N") { // проверяем происходила ли активация пользователя
        $toSend = Array();
        $toSend["PASSWORD"] = $arFields["CONFIRM_PASSWORD"];
        $toSend["EMAIL"] = $arFields["EMAIL"];
        $toSend["USER_ID"] = $arFields["ID"];
        $toSend["USER_IP"] = $arFields["USER_IP"];
        $toSend["USER_HOST"] = $arFields["USER_HOST"];
        $toSend["LOGIN"] = $arFields["LOGIN"];
        $toSend["NAME"] = (trim ($arFields["NAME"]) == "")? $toSend["NAME"] = htmlspecialchars('Не указано'): $arFields["NAME"];
        $toSend["LAST_NAME"] = (trim ($arFields["LAST_NAME"]) == "")? $toSend["LAST_NAME"] = htmlspecialchars('Не указано'): $arFields["LAST_NAME"];
        CEvent::Send ("NEW_USER", "s1", $toSend, "N", 1);
    }
    return $arFields;
}

function SendMailOffThreeDay(){   // отправка письма менеджеру после 3 дней ожидания регистрации пользователя
    CModule::IncludeModule('main');
    $filter = Array("ACTIVE" => "N");
    $rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="personal_country"), ($order="desc"), $filter); // выбираем пользователей
    while($arUser = $rsUsers->GetNext()) {
        $nextWeek = strtotime(date('d.m.Y H:i:s')) - strtotime($arUser["DATE_REGISTER"]);
        if($nextWeek > 259200) {  // время создания больше 3 дней
            $filter_user["USER_ID"] = $arUser["ID"];
            $filter_user["LOGIN"] = $arUser["LOGIN"];
            CEvent::Send ("NEW_USER", "s1", $filter_user, "N", 85);
        }
    };
    return 'SendMailOffThreeDay();';
}
```

Как мне добавить в эти функции еще и вложения, отправляюемые при регистрации (*напр. UF_DOCUMENT_6*)

если посмотреть что внутри вот так :

```
<?
global $USER;
$arFilter = array("ID" => $USER->GetID());
$arParams["SELECT"] = array("UF_DOCUMENT_6");
$arRes = CUser::GetList($by,$desc,$arFilter,$arParams);
    if ($res = $arRes->Fetch()) {
        ?><pre><? print_r($res["UF_DOCUMENT_6"])?></pre><?
    }
?>
```

то вернется просто строка **7232967** , которая ничего по сути мне не дает. можно ли как то прикрутить функционал вложений из почтовых шаблонов ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

а как понять, вам строка по сути ничего не дает?
она дает вам все.
Это ид картинки с вашего сайта. А дальше `CFile::GetPath`, или получайте полную инфу про файл, ройтесь уже по документации битрикса.
Это если получить путь файла.
А если ва мпросто во вложения нужно добавить.... То вот реально?

```
CEvent::Send(
   string event,
   mixed lid,
   array fields,
   string duplicate="Y",
   int message_id="",
   array files,
   string language_id
 )
```

, где `files` - Массив id файлов, то-есть как раз таки та строка, которая "вам ничего не дает", запханая в массив.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/114106/blog/9787/

посмотри это решение, я таким обошелся когда встала такая задача

Comment: Тут он вручную прописывает какой файл отправлять, мне надо отправлять файлы которые попали в поле юзера "дополнительные поля" ( при регистрации) 1 скрин, они всегда разные для каждого юзера и письма соотв.